# C++ 2d array runtime error

Tags: c++, arrays

doing some assignment, here's a function to count negative numbers in a dynamically allocated 2D array:

```
 void numberOfNegs(int** arrayPointer, int n) {
    int counter{ 0 };
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < n; i++){
        for (int j{ 0 }; j < n; j++){
            if (arrayPointer[i][j] < 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Seems legit to me, but the debugger throws this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00C25D9A in *.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.

Please, help

Here's more code on how I casted it

```
    std::cin >> x;

int** theMatrix = new int*[x];
for (int i{ 0 }; i < x; i++){
    theMatrix[x] = new int[x];
}

std::cout << "Please enter a matrix " << x << std::endl;

for (int i{ 0 }; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j{ 0 }; j < x; j++) {
        std::cin >> theMatrix[x][x];
    }
}

 numberOfNegs(theMatrix, x)
```

Comment: What are you passing in?

Comment: If your data structure isn't sane, there's no way this will work. Wouldn't using `std::vector` save you a lot of pain here? That `for (int j{0}; ...` notation is downright bizarre, too. Why not `int j = 0`?

Comment: You should try debugging. And also post a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: How did you allocate `arrayPointer`? More code, please...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, we need more information.

Comment: `0xcdcdcdcd` is a special bit pattern in the MSVC debug heap implementation with which newly allocated memory is overwritten. It indicates that you're trying to use uninitialized memory as a pointer and dereference it, so chances are that the inner arrays of your 2D array are not all properly allocated/put into the outer array.

Comment: Here is more info on 0xcdcdcdcd: http://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892

Comment: Added the allocation code

Comment: i wonder why you you this fancy curly brackets everywhere and at the same time a "dynamically allocated 2d array" instead of a standard container. Looks like an anachronism to me :P

Comment: it's just a college assignment,need to follow the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initialisation problem is here:

```
for (int i{ 0 }; i < x; i++){
    theMatrix[x] = new int[x];
}
```

You are using `x` as the array index, while your (probably) mean `i`. Your current code just creates an array for the last element, `x` times. Change it to:

```
for (int i{ 0 }; i < x; i++){
    theMatrix[i] = new int[x];
}
```

You may also want to adjust this code:

```
for (int i{ 0 }; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j{ 0 }; j < x; j++) {
        std::cin >> theMatrix[x][x];
    }
}
```

To:

```
for (int i{ 0 }; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j{ 0 }; j < x; j++) {
        std::cin >> theMatrix[i][j];
    }
}
```